# Multithreading using the thread pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, taskfactory

I have the following code:

```
    private static void SplitTilesRecursive(Image original, int level)
    {
        int mapWidth = GetMapWidth(level);
        int tilesOnSide = mapWidth/TileSize;


        using (Image resized = ResizeImage(original, new Size(mapWidth, mapWidth)))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < tilesOnSide; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < tilesOnSide; y++)
                {
                    CropAndSaveTile(resized, x, y, level);
                }
        }


        if (level > 0)
            SplitTilesRecursive(original, level - 1);
    }

    private static void CropAndSaveTile(Image image, int x, int y, int level)
    {
        var info = (CropInfo) o;
        var cropArea = new Rectangle(x * TileSize, y * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);


        using (var bmpImage = new Bitmap(image))
        using (Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat))
        {
            string filename = String.Format(TileFilename, level, x, y);

            // the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used implicitly
            bmpCrop.Save(Path.Combine(OutputDir, filename));
            Console.WriteLine("Processed " + filename);
        }
    }
```

The method `CropAndSaveTile` takes a awhile, so I want to split that task off to a new thread using a thread pool. I've tried to accomplish this using [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456). The problem is that I need to pass those 4 parameters to the thread, so I had to create a class which I could cast to an object.

```
    private class CropInfo
    {
        public CropInfo(Image image, int x, int y, int level)
        {
            Image = image;
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Level = level;
        }

        public Image Image { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
    }

    private static void SplitTilesRecursive(Image original, int level)
    {
        // ...
        using (Image resized = ResizeImage(original, new Size(mapWidth, mapWidth)))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < tilesOnSide; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < tilesOnSide; y++)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(CropAndSaveTile, new CropInfo(resized, x, y, level));
                }
        }
        // ...
    }

    private static void CropAndSaveTile(object o)
    {
        var info = (CropInfo) o;
        // ...
    }
```

This almost works. The problem is that `new Bitmap(info.Image)` throws an `ArgumentException` (Parameter is not valid). I've tested this without using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` and instead calling the method directly using `CropAndSaveTile(new CropInfo(resized, x, y, level));` and it works fine. Something is happening between  `StartNew` and and the thread runs. Could this be a synchronization issue caused by when `SplitTilesRecursive` ends the loop and `resized` is disposed of? And if not, how can I properly pass multiple parameters to a thread to be used as part of a thread pool?

Comment: Are you using the same instance of `resized` for all the tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to create a class?  You can just do this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>CropandSaveTile(resized, y, y,  level));
```

The language will create a class for you under the covers as a "closure".

Comment: I was worried that a closure would cause problems, for example if x or y changes before the thread can execute.

Comment: The closure does the same thing you're trying to do.  It will copy the values from x and y into members of a compiler-generated class.  The only issue would be if you modified reference variable data.  i.e. if you changed the memory that the Image references.  But, you'd get the same problem if you manually created a class

Comment: Okay, but I'm asking is how do I do this so that I don't run into this same problem? I thought I was getting away with that by using a class but I overlooked the fact that the object doesn't get copied to the instance but instead referenced.

Comment: Same problem with the Image?  I assume ResizeImage is making a new copy of the data, if you don't let anything else have access to resized, you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use local copies of `x` and `y` inside the loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < tilesOnSide; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < tilesOnSide; y++)
    {
        int x1 = x;
        int y1 = y;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CropAndSaveTile(resized, x1, y1, level));
    }
```

This guarantees that each lambda sees a separate pair of `x` and `y` values.